# Accepting Stack Overflow Careers Invitation

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

A couple weeks ago I received an email inviting me to create a Stack Overflow Careers profile. I clicked on the link and filled out several of the fields provided. I didn't really have time to finish it, so I saved it and promptly forgot changing it later.

Then two days ago I got an email saying, "We noticed you have not accepted our invitation to join Stack Overflow Careers. Only 3 days remain before it expires..." And provides a link to accept the invitation.

Is there some way to know when I've officially accepted the invitation? I assumed that just by filling out some of the fields that would have automatically accepted the invitation. I went back and added a lot more information and got my Careers profile to 100% complete, but still no indication that I had accepted the invitation.

Now when go back to the second email and click to accept the invitation it says that I have already have a profile, no need to accept the invitation below.

At what point does the invitation get accepted? I'm kind of confused why I got a second email inviting me to Stack Overflow Careers.

Comment: I've had my careers profile fully filled out for a couple months and recently received a couple invitations to join careers.  Not the same but similar.

Comment: FWIW, I received invites months ago, and even after the 2-week "deadline" expired, I was still able to use that link to create an account.

Comment: Would you be able to forward the emails you received to `careers@stackoverflow.com` and mention this meta post as well? It looks like we have a bug here but just trying to get to the bottom of why it occurred!

Comment: Yes, I can do that soon.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think I've worked out what happened in this specific case.

You were sent an invite on 10th November at 17:15 UTC (invitation 1).

On 11th November at 00:42 UTC you used the "Create a profile" link on Stack Overflow Careers (or maybe clicked a link on Stack Overflow that took you to the same place), and linked your existing Stack Overflow account. This internally creates another invitation we'll call invitation 2.

You can probably see where this is going.

Some time later you clicked your link to accept invitation 1. We see that you've already started a profile, so we just take you to where you can resume creating it.

This means invitation 1 never actually gets accepted.

The whole thing of invitations and having a separate account for Careers is, frankly, weird - we're doing a lot of work in this area right now. All of this stuff will go away - you'll have one Careers account and there will be no more invites, so these kinds of problems will disappear (and presumably, entirely new kinds of problems will be created).

Comment: Okay, thanks for looking into that for me. I just wanted to be sure I wouldn't forfeit my invitation. I'm looking forward to all the changes that will happen soon. I agree, new kinds of problems always happen.

Comment: ...New problems like the mismatch between my SO email and my careers email not being the same and getting invites for Careers when I already have a page...